# Rate limiting an .apply method with _.throttle

Tags: javascript, function, methods, underscore.js, throttling

Is it possible to rate-limit, throttle or debounce something like `this[act].apply(this, data)`? With underscore or something else? I've tried a bunch of stuff, like

`_.throttle(/* different permutations of combined args */)`

`_.throttle.apply(/* same */)`

`_.throttle.apply(myArgs)(throttleArgs)`

`_.throttle(throttleArgs).apply(myArgs)`

etc. Some yield errors, some freeze execution and some call the apply method with (correct scope and args but) no throttling. Any ideas? Using CoffeeScript and these are class methods.

Answer (score 2):

Since the original function you are calling

```
this[act].apply(this, data)
```

uses `this`, I assume you are calling it from within a method on an object. The question, how to get `this` from here to there? Many higher-order functions are designed to call the underlying function with the same `this` they themselves are called with, using the following kind of skeleton:

```
function higher_order_function(fn) {
  return function() {
    return fn.apply(this, arguments);
  };
}
```

What this means is, if I have a object with a method

```
var obj = {
  val: 42,
  print: function() { console.log(this.val); }
}
```

And then I want to transform the `print` function:

```
obj.newPrint = higher_order_function(obj.print);
```

I can now call `obj.newPrint`, and underneath, `this` will be used to invoke `print`, and everything works as expected.

There are alternative designs for such things, involving passing around contexts (`this`) explictly and giving them as separate parameters to functions, but the approach above is usually cleaner and "just works".

This is how `_.throttle` works. If you look at the source code, you see it doing things like

```
return function() {
  ...
  context = this;
  args = arguments;
  ...
  result = func.apply(context, args);
};
```

This means, to invoke your code in throttled fashion, all you need to do is arrange to call it with `this`.

Let's assume the original code you are calling is in a function called `act`.

```
var obj = {
  act: function(act) {
    this[act].apply(this, data);
  }
};
```

To make a throttled version of `act` (here, we make it directly on the object; you could accomplish a similar thing by putting it on the prototype, see below):

```
obj.throttledAct = _.throttle(obj.act);
```

Then simply call

```
obj.throttledAct('act1')
```

If you are programming with prototypes:

```
Foo.prototype.func = function(act) { this[act].apply(this, data) };
```

Then you can put the throttled version on the prototype with:

```
Foo.prototype.throttledFunc = _.throttle(Foo.prototype.func);
```

and everything will work as expected.

If for some reason you want to create a stand-alone version of the throttled function, without putting it in an object or or prototype:

```
var throttledFunc = _.throttled(func);
```

You can then call it with `call` or `apply` to force the value of `this`:

```
throttledFunc.call(obj, 'act1`);
```

But in either case, how does the parameter `'act1'` get passed through to the underlying function. This is also accomplished via the line in the implementation of `_.throttle` that reads

```
result = func.apply(context, args);
```

Here `args` is the arguments being passed to the function constructed by `_.throttle`, and `apply` is used to pass them, along with `this`, to the underlying function. Note that `_.throttle` itself also takes additional parameters to be passed to the underlying function, but that "burns them in" rather than letting them be specified each time the throttled function is called.

#### Your attempts

```
_.throttle(/* different permutations of combined args */)
_.throttle.apply(/* same */)
_.throttle.apply(myArgs)(throttleArgs)
_.throttle(throttleArgs).apply(myArgs)
```

All of these suffer from the same problem, which is that `_.throttle` must be **passed a function** to be throttled, and returns a function which you then call to obtain the throttled behavior. The last one is possibly closest, assuming that `throttleArgs` is the function to be throttled, and `myArgs` is actually `this, myArgs`.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer! In the midst of something so I'm waiting to accept it until I'm back to solving this. For context, I'm using CoffeeScript and these are class methods.